# Taking R,G,B individually from a <cv::vec3b> vector

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

To make my question clearer, please see the codes.

```
vector<cv::Vec3b> v_char; // the vector that I am storing my r,g,b values, or b,g,r in this case since it's opencv.
```

I know to print out the value of use the values, I can just simply take from image directly, something like this.

```
b = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
g = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
r = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
```

However, without the use of the image(imagine image is gone), and I only want the values from the vector, v_char where all the image values have been stored, let's say for instance, I only want the r value, how do I retrieve it? Tried searching it up on the internet and playing around with the codes, but to no avail :(

EDIT: MORE DETAILS
The vector, v_char is just storing the value of one row of the image. So for example: I want to find and print out all the r values of the particular row which can be found in the v_char vector. I can use a for loop, but how do I declare out the r values only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vec3b v_char` itself is a vector of 3 values which can be accessed as `first values = v_char.val[0]`, `second values = v_char.val[1]`, `third values = v_char.val[2]`. As you need only the `red` values so, just access all the values in  `v_char.val[0]` for the whole vector.

so through a `for loop` try to get all the values of:

```
v_char[i].val[0]; // "i" represents the index of "for loop" for a given row
```

Comment: +1 and accepted answer for u. Thanks. Didn't know about the .val[] thing. Learnt something today(:

Comment: Hello guys, quick question. Are red values accessible from v_char.val[2] or v_char.val[0]?

Comment: `v_char.val[2]` becasue OpenCV loads an image in BGR format.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know without knowing your data structure, but likely something like this.

Assuming `j` is the row index, `i` is the column index, and the stride of your rows is neatly packed.

```
auto &px = v_char[j * width + i];
```

Comment: nope. It doesn't work. Actually, the vector, v_char is just storing the value of one row of the image. So for example: I want to find and  print out all the r values of the particular row which can be found in the v_char vector. I can use a for loop, but how do I declare out the r values only?

Comment: +1 for u anyway, but hope you know what I mean now and is able to help me. Thanks.

Comment: you are asking if OpenCV has something built in to save you from writing a for loop?

Comment: nope. I am trying to do something like "r = image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2];" but for vector, but I just can't get the right format:/

Comment: something like v_char[i].at<cv::Vec3b>[2]; but its the wrong format.